# how to filter floor calculated value on select with joins where it is not null?

Tags: sql, magento

I have query with joins (in magento) :

```
    SELECT FLOOR(rating.rating_summary/20) AS `rating_value`,
           COUNT(*) AS `count`
    FROM `catalog_product_flat_3` AS `e`
    INNER JOIN `catalogsearch_result` AS `search_result` ON search_result.product_id=e.entity_id
    AND search_result.query_id='218'
    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id
    AND price_index.website_id = '1'
    AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
    INNER JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `rating` ON rating.entity_pk_value = e.entity_id
    AND rating.store_id = 0;
```

It is required to filter out rows with NULL in `rating_value` or `count < 1`

```
    +--------------+-------+
    | rating_value | count |
    +--------------+-------+
    |         NULL |     0 |
    +--------------+-------+
    1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

but for some reason where i try `WHERE count > 0` or `rating_value IS NOT NULL` it saids that subject column  `rating_value`, `count` is not exists, what do I do wrong ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.  A column alias defined in a `SELECT` cannot be used in the `WHERE`.  You need a subquery or to repeat the expression:

```
WHERE FLOOR(rating.rating_summary/20) IS NOT NULL
```

This is equivalent to:

```
WHERE rating.rating_summary IS NOT NULL
```

The `count` needs to go in a `HAVING` clause, which I would write as:

```
HAVING count = 0 OR rating_value IS NOT NULL
```

I would also expect your query to have a `GROUP BY` clause, which it seems to be missing.

So I suspect you want:

```
SELECT FLOOR(rating.rating_summary/20) AS `rating_value`,
       COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM `catalog_product_flat_3` pf INNER JOIN
     `catalogsearch_result` sr
      ON sr.product_id = pf.entity_id AND
         sr.query_id = 218 INNER JOIN
      `catalog_product_index_price` pip
      ON pip.entity_id = pf.entity_id AND
        pip.website_id = 1 AND
        pip.customer_group_id = 0 INNER JOIN
      `review_entity_summary` r
     ON r.entity_pk_value = pf.entity_id AND r.store_id = 0
GROUP BY FLOOR(r.rating_summary/20)
HAVING `count` = 0 OR rating_value IS NULL;
```